# No route matches [DELETE] "/todo_lists.1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following a tutorial and I'm stuck with this issue. In the video for the tutorial that I'm watching, the code works just fine but I am getting this error even though I copied the code from the tutorial exactly.

The todo list controller

```
def destroy
  @todo_list.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Todo list was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Show page:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2 class="todo_list_title"><%= @todo_list.title %></h2>
<p class="todo_list_sub_title"><%= @todo_list.description %></p>

<div id="todo_items_wrapper">
  <%= render @todo_list.todo_items %>
  <div id="form">
    <%= render "todo_items/form" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="links">
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_todo_list_path(@todo_list) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Delete', todo_lists_path(@todo_list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', todo_lists_path %>  
</div>
```

Rake Routes gives

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                 Controller#Action
complete_todo_list_todo_item PATCH  /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id/complete(.:format) todo_items#complete
        todo_list_todo_items GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)              todo_items#index
                             POST   /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)              todo_items#create
     new_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/new(.:format)          todo_items#new
    edit_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id/edit(.:format)     todo_items#edit
         todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)          todo_items#show
                             PATCH  /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)          todo_items#update
                             PUT    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)          todo_items#update
                             DELETE /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)          todo_items#destroy
                  todo_lists GET    /todo_lists(.:format)                                       todo_lists#index
                             POST   /todo_lists(.:format)                                       todo_lists#create
               new_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/new(.:format)                                   todo_lists#new
              edit_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id/edit(.:format)                              todo_lists#edit
                   todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                   todo_lists#show
                             PATCH  /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                   todo_lists#update
                             PUT    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                   todo_lists#update
                             DELETE /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                   todo_lists#destroy
                        root GET    /                                                           todo_lists#index
```

Comment: What does `rake routes` give you?

Comment: I updated the post and included the result from rake routes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `todo_list_path` instead of todo_list**s**_path :)

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', todo_list_path(@todo_list), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %> |
```

It's a classic error. Look at `“/todo_lists.1”` if you see this dot you probably use wrong helper.

Comment: I'm still very new to Rails, would you be able to tell me which helper I should use?

Comment: He did, note the singular list in `todo_list_path`.

Comment: @TheMansa use todo_list_path

Comment: @BradWerth His comment did not originally include that information but thanks @Arsen!

Comment: No problem! Thanks again.